# .NET core console application showing (0 project) in solution explorer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have just started to use Visual Studio 2019 and I cannot run my newly created C# .NET core Console App. It was created using the Console Application template as shown:
[image]
there is no option to run program and it is showing that there are 0 projects under the solution explorer.
[image]
dotnet should be successfully installed, `dotnet -- info` returns .NET SDK (5.0.405) and running 'dotnet' in the folder with the .csproj file runs the console app, printing 'Hello world'. I've also checked that dotnet is included in System Properties -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> path.
The console app was created using the .NET core console application template as shown:

How do I run the console app in Visual Studio 19?

Comment: Assuming there's a .csproj file you could easily add it to the solution. Right-click on the solution in solution explorer then Add -> Existing Project...

Comment: I can't explain why it didn't automatically add the project to the solution, but you should be able to do so manually.

Comment: You need to include the project in the solution. Right click on the solution and choose "Add->Existing project", then locate the "ConsoleApp1.csproj" file.

Comment: ah i see, i'll do just that for now to complete the .net tutorial im following